# PRISM 5 + MahApps.Metro

Tags: wpf, prism, mahapps.metro

Does anyone tried hooking up PRISM 5 and Mahapps.Metro? Is Mahapps compitable with PRISM? I see its MetroWindow is inheriting from Window though.

Kindly guide me what could be the issue I may encounter going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just made a quick sample in order to verify they would be compatible. You may find the **HelloWorld QuickStart** with the **MahApps.Metro** package configured:

- [HelloWorldWithMahApps](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3EE28791A0DF3126!118&authkey=!ACnGas56YDcuZJY&ithint=file,.zip)

In order to configure the Shell View, the configuration would be straightforward on the xaml page and its ***Code Behind***, where you would make it inherit from **MetroWindow** with no major problems.

You may find helpful the following **MahApps Tutorial Quickstart** Guide:

- [MahApps.Metro Quick Start](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html)

Regards.

Comment: Thats perfect, Thank you so much. I have already started playing around and able to run a basic shell view using prism assemblies. Have to see how it goes after adding more functionality. But I will download the above provided sample.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am glad it helped you. Therefore, don't forget to Vote or Accept the answer if you think it was useful so we can keep the forum clean with resolved questions for the new incoming users.

Comment: One more question here, I am on my way coming up with a proof of concept about usability.
I Would like to maintain same data/biz layer between Asp.net MVC & WPF. 

That said, I have a data layer with EF5 + Repository pattern + interface based biz layer. In Asp.net MVC am using unity bootsrapper.

Should I go and use Unitybootstrapper in WPF too ? and does it support pluging in dll based Modules?.

Please help me here

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/steve600/PrismMahAppsSample) you can find a working example on how you can use MahApps with Prism.

It shows you how to use

- `Tiles`
- `Flyouts`
- `Popups`
- I18n
- Themes
- `Right|LeftWindowCommands`